# Make one time only activation code to python code, and make updates available?

Tags: python-3.x, updates, activation

I'm coding a program to do some action with webdriver and Autoit in python, I want to do two things before I start selling my code:

1. Add onetime activation code to my software on one PC, like to make the program works only on one pc.
2. Make my program able to receive updates from the internet once I add to the code some more features or correct some others.

is it possible only with Python? or what is the method statement to do it?

Answer (score 0):

On client side you need use hard-disk serial or/and uuid of partition or Operational System timestamp + something to generate serial code .

On server side , you need a API to store hard disk serial to validate if this is a computer valid . And you client on load check if activaction is valid .

The second question i can't answer .

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part of your question:

Create a text file with the latest version of your application and put it on your webserver e.g. http://download.example.com/example-app-version.txt to get and read its value later.

On your python code download and read the text (for Python 3+ use 'import urllib.request' and urllib.request.urlretrieve) when your app  runs and compare it against the installed version (if statement).
E.g.

```
if latestVer > installedVer:
    #update
else:
    #application continues
```